# Format to add standard code blocks within Markdown lists

Tags: markdown, code-formatting

I've found that I can't get code blocks within numbered lists.

For example, when I add a code block by indenting by four spaces normally like below:

```
1. Do the first thing

    $ git stuff
    $ git other stuff 

2. second thing:

    $ git more stuff
```

it comes out like this, where the `$ git` lines are normal text and are not formatted as code:

> 1. Do the first thing
>
>    $ git stuff
>      $ git other stuff
> 2. second thing:
>
>    $ git more stuff

I can use the backticks to do it, i.e.

```
1. Do the first things

    `$ git stuff`  
    `$ git other stuff` 

2. second thing:

    `$ git more stuff`
```

but I would like to do the blocks 'normally' (4 space indent) if I can.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) you need to do extra indentation; +4 spaces or +1 tab (8/2, respectively, from column 0).

```
1. Item 1

        $git stuff
        $git other stuff

2. Item 2

        $git more stuff
```

Those newlines are necessary.