# Markdown: Problems with numbered list paragraphs containing code element

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I created a [README.md](https://github.com/codingaround/easyfglrxinstall/blob/master/README.md) file on GitHub and there are some markdown problems I can't find a solution to.

When I enter this (The dots represent space signs):

Instructions:..
....1. First sentence..
....2. Second sentence..

........This is some code.

....3. Third sentence..
....4. Fourth sentence

It renders to this:

Instructions:
    1. First sentence
    2. Second sentence

```
    This is some code.

3. Third sentence
4. Fourth sentence
```

How can I separate the code block from the numbered list?

I would also like to know how I can tell Markdown to ignore Markdown syntax so I don't have to use dots as a representation of space signs.

Comment: can you post the link to the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [markdown format - can't do standard code blocks (4 space indents) within lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271188/markdown-format-cant-do-standard-code-blocks-4-space-indents-within-lists)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this?

```
Instructions:

1. First sentence
2. Second sentence

    `This is some code.`

3. Third sentence
4. Fourth sentence
```

It wouldn't indent each point, however your example with the dots doesn't do it either.
If the spacing between `Instructions:` and the rest is not what you want, you can use the double space after it and on the two following lines.

UPDATE:
After a little fiddling, if you want to keep the numbering of the list and put some code that's relative to a single item on the list you should indent the code block.
Also, have a new line before the first element of the list seems to help.

Comment: Using this http://github-preview.herokuapp.com, it seems to work. You can add extra ` around the code block and remove the 4 spaces actually.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. That's because you're indenting the whole block so it's interpreted as a code block.

Comment: But I have to indent it. Otherwise numbers 3 and 4 will break and show 1, 2 instead.