# How to remove extra line space on GitHub markdown bullets/lists?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

The GitHub markdown code:

```
1. First item
* subitem
1. Second item
```

Generates a big space between the `First`, `Second` and the `subitem`:

[image]

How to make the `subitem` close to the first item, instead of exactly on the middle of them?

This is a Photoshop I did to illustrate the correct output:

[image]

---

Related questions:

1. [Multi paragraph list items, OR preventing numbered list auto formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192894/multi-paragraph-list-items-or-preventing-numbered-list-auto-formatting)
2. [Markdown: Problems with numbered list paragraphs containing code element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037311/markdown-problems-with-numbered-list-paragraphs-containing-code-element)

Comment: I believe the extra space is a mere artifact of the way Github's markdown rendering engine chooses to display it, and there's not much you can do about it. Other markdown engines may display it differently.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to indent the sublist with at least 4 spaces:

```
1. First item
    * subitem
2. Second item
```

Comment: what about tabs?

Comment: Need at least three spaces: i.e. the * aligns with "F" in 1.

Comment: This works for removing the extra space, but other formatting (e.g., links) are removed.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this going from a primary to secondary item. It is possible from a secondary to tertiary list, however. This is due to GitHub's styling of the markdown, not an inherent issue with the markdown itself.

See [this document](https://gist.github.com/dupuy/1855764) for details on what is possible regarding different layout styles.

Answer (score 0):

An admittably "hacky" but still working solution:

1. Choose any character from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp).
2. Copy it and paste it as bullet point:

```
1. First item  [< two spaces for the linebreak]
◦ subitem1  [< two spaces for the linebreak]
◦ subitem2
2. Second item
```

3. Don't forget the two spaces for the linebreak.

Comment: This works in the sense that there is no extra line added between the first item and the subitem, but if (like mine) your editor auto-removes trailing whitespace, you'll have to manually insert <br> everywhere. Tried it, source text became ugly, went back to having an extra line and a readable readme even when not formated. Also, you'll lose indentation.

Comment: Two spaces serve as a newline which is not required in list environment.