# GitLab: How to add (remove) extra line space on markdown bullets/lists?

Tags: gitlab, markdown

I've found related question, mine about GitLab, those about GitHub: [How to remove extra line space on GitHub markdown bullets/lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113083/how-to-remove-extra-line-space-on-github-markdown-bullets-lists) and one answer is to use 4 spaces and another:

> You cannot do this ... This is due to
>   GitHub's styling of the markdown, not an inherent issue with the
>   markdown itself.

I've made a list and in GitLab GUI I see it like that:

```
o ABC

o ABC

  o ABC
  o ABC
o ABC
```

Extra empty line before secondary list but no line after. I prefer to add space after secondary too, however deleting all empty lines in list would look good too. Below is my markdown, it has 4 spaces for secondary list and I've tried to add `<br/>` as per [Create two blank lines in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543454/create-two-blank-lines-in-markdown) but it breaks list structure after that (which also results in disappearing empty lines between primary list entries btw).

```
  - datapool
  - specific
    - jmx
    - config
<br/> (that is temp try, see above text)
  - python
```

Could it be done in GitLab?

Answer (score 5):

I found that alternating between the `+` and `-` unordered list indicators produces the desired result.

```
- Item 1
   - SubItem 1
   - SubItem 2

+ Item 2
  + SubItem 1
  + SubItem 2

- Item 3
   - SubItem 1
   - SubItem 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Small mistake: should have put `<br/>` on same level as secondary list (indent with 4 spaces) - then extra line is seen in GUI.